# Edit PE header using C#

Tags: c#, resources, portable-executable

What I am trying to do is actually very basic, but I can't find an appropriate entry point.
I have an executable (not CLR) and I would like to add (and later read) some text to the Resources of the file.

What I found so far is [PeNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeNet/) for enumerating PE headers and an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648004(v=vs.85).aspx) regarding resource modification with C Methods. But this requires me to complile a string into a resource?...

**Edit:**
Using [this sample](http://hintdesk.com/c-add-resources-to-native-executable-file-with-updateresource/) I tried to change a resource, but I'm losing the content of the executable after I run the code.

Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bDeleteExistingResources);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, uint lpType, uint lpName, ushort wLanguage, byte[] lpData, uint cbData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);

    var path = @"c:\temp\some.exe";
    var arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my text");

    IntPtr ipTarget = BeginUpdateResource(outPath, false);
    if (UpdateResource(ipTarget, 6/*RT_STRING*/, 1234/*some name*/, 1033, arr, (uint)arr.Length))
    {
        EndUpdateResource(ipTarget, false);
    }
```

Comment: [Click](http://hintdesk.com/c-add-resources-to-native-executable-file-with-updateresource/).

Comment: Rebuilding the EXE file so it gets an updated .rsrc section is not exactly "very basic".  The file format is about the worst possible choice for a dbase.  Worse than worst if you do this on a machine with the typical shrink-wrapped malware installed.  Google "c# beginupdateresource" to get somewhere.

Comment: Thats a start. Thanks! But I lose the previous content when I update the res...? What am I missing there?